# Why won't ActiveSheet.Name function work in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new (separate) workbooks for each worksheets from Test_Main but I am getting a

> 1004 error

in this line of code stating that I need a new name and cannot use this name as it is in use.

```
wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"
```

Is my code right? Or is there any other alternative for this ?

Thanks in advance !

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim a As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count  'counts all the sheets

For i = 1 To a 'loops for all sheets
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name <> "Test_Main" Then 'rule out the main sheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1) 'new workbook has 1 worksheet by deafult
wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"

wb.Close savechages = True

End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select

MsgBox ("Task Completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Thisworkbook.worksheets(i).Name` instead.

Comment: It works! Thanks alot ! And if I want to save is as a .csv file then is this the right syntax: wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name & ".csv"

Comment: No, you need to specify the `FileFormat` argument as well.

Comment: okay so then is this the right syntax ? wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV

Comment: Update: I tried this but it won't work :(

Comment: What does "won't work" actually mean?

Comment: I am getting the 1004 Error: Cannot save the file under the name of an already opened file. There is already a document open with the name you specified. Choose a different name for the workbook or close the open document before saving.

Comment: Then you've currently got a file by that name open. You can't have two files with the same name open at once. It's probably an artefact of your earlier testing.